# Providing answers to code that is different, but more efficient than the OP's code

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer

I sometimes provide answers to an OP that is essentially a fix to their code that they can understand, but they may not be the best answer for the problem. A recent example has led me here, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099465/filtering-and-creating-a-column-based-on-the-date-column/54099938#54099938) (disclaimer: the accepted answer is mine), but there is a better answer posted.

I am asking if, for a given piece of code provided by the OP, it is better to provide a completely different solution that would be more efficient computationally that the OP does not understand (as you can clearly see by the comments underneath the second answer on the provided question)?

This better answer would perpetuate "better coding practices" for future viewers trying to solve the same problem.

Or an answer that seeks to modify and clarify the OP's existing code to make it functional, while also providing an explanation as to what OP did wrong in practice?

Comment: Try to get out of the habit of saying "above" and "underneath" when pointing at other answers; as you can see, they move based on voting.

Comment: To add on to @JoshCaswell's point, the cardinality may be *completely different* if they're sorting the answers in a different way.

Comment: also acceptance and addition and deletion.. you can't be sure that the other answer you reference will even stick around.

Comment: I have changed “underneath” to “posted”. Thanks for the tips, they are quite valid!

Comment: I tend to just modify what they have. If I can slip in a better way to do what they're already doing without changing too much, I'll put a comment in the code to explain it

Comment: I usually write the answer they want at the beginning then write (in the same answer) the alternative. If the changes are to big, I usually just write a summary in the hope they'll do their own research.

Comment: @d_kennetz If I reference other answers I will link to them directly by using the small [share] button below left of the post you want to reference. So you have an absolute link to the post you're talking about

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I wrote the other answer on that Q&A. Your answer is perfectly fine, and I don't feel you *need* to adjust it.

However, just as you *shouldn't* write C as if you are writing C++ or vice-versa, Python (and Pandas) have certain paradigms. In this case, Pandas is *specifically designed* for vectorised computations. Which is why I offered a solution more in line with Pandas' philosophy.

That doesn't mean your answer is wrong. Multiple answers are encouraged: we don't close questions just because there's an accepted answer. Indeed, the focus shouldn't be on the original poster, but the *problem*. Other users will visit the Q&A, and they may find the vectorised solution more helpful. Likewise, others may just be looking to patch their code. That's their prerogative.

Comment: Just to add, when I do start and end with an alternative approach, I *try* (as here) to give an explanation *why* I'm doing so. Telling someone their approach or starting point is "wrong" or "inefficient" doesn't often add value (not just for OP, but wider audience) unless you indicate *why* that's the case.

Comment: I recognized your name, thanks for the post. My question was purely out of curiosity  (no malice or annoyance). I was just truly curious as to how I should go about this in the future. I like the portion you wrote "we don't close questions because there's an accepted answer" as this is something I actually didn't pay much attention to, but is a very relevant point. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @d_kennetz as a suggestion, you could take both approaches in the same answer. Part 1, provide the most direct answer to the OP's question. Part 2, include an improved version including discussion of the reasons it is better as per jpp's suggestions. I think this would make for an extremely strong & useful answer.

Comment: I agree completely and will likely be my process going forward. Answer by @Makoto recommended this and I think it is an excellent solution to a question.

Answer (score 15):

You're trying to *help*.  Sure, optimized code *can* help, but that's not the point; the OP likely doesn't care how fast the code runs so long as *it runs*.

In the circumstance where a straight-up optimization is possible, I've espoused a pattern in which I answer a question and provide a more optimal solution *along side* the answer as a means of comparison.  This way, you have a chance of enlightening the OP as to what their problem was, what the solution would be should they go down their current path, and what a *better* approach is.

Don't just go for code efficiency, since that breaks [the First Rule of Code Optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimization) anyway.

Comment: I'm always puzzled what to do when folks copy SQL injection from OP code to the answer to keep most of original code... trolling? "unfriendly and unkind"? or maybe perfectly ok and welcome because they afraid to "optimize" the code? I'm not sure if trying to help OP should go that far to keep as much of original code as possible...

Comment: I really like your point about providing an optimal solution along side the answer as comparison. I think that is a good idea!

Answer (score 8):

I often add efficiency / performance advice to my answers. I do it like this.

1. answer the question directly.
2. point out the possible improvement. If it's simple enough to be in the scope of a SO answers, I just write it out. If it's a big algorithm change I sometimes add a comment to my answer with a link to some conceptual material.

This, I believe, serves SO's teaching purpose without hijacking questions. It's also respectful of questioners' effort.

Comment: I agree the best solution is to include *both* of your points. Doing just the first *when it's not advisable* (SQL injection; Python `eval` / `exec` come to mind) is sometimes worse than doing just the second. I cringe every time I see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553721/using-a-string-variable-as-a-variable-name) where `exec` is the highest voted answer. We just hope everyone clicks to get to the marked duplicate *or* give the second solution priority.