# How to handle a question which implies, more than an answer, a code peer review with colleagues for the asker

Tags: discussion, specific-question, comments, scope

I have partially reviewed the code submitted in the question *[Why does this C program fail with GCC O2 and O3 optimisation level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66659054/why-does-this-c-program-fail-with-gcc-o2-and-o3-optimisation-level)*, and it seems to me that the asker needs more a code peer review with colleagues than an answer.

I've started to check the defects and could probably assume a kind of code review, but it is the right thing to do? From what I know about SO/SE and my understanding of the CoC, SO seems not the right place for that. If anyway I try to help the asker on it, as fixing / troubleshoot asker's code seems not a answer material here, even if I feel it is the root cause of the question, should it be appropriate then by the comments?

Maybe I'm biased, as a professional developer I'm used to code peer reviews and await similar practice / culture from other developers / askers where I shouldn't.

I've searched for similar questions on this subject and found:

*[Dealing with a question that is asking for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390274/dealing-with-a-question-that-is-asking-for-code)*

*[Providing answers to code that is different, but more efficient than the OP's code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378750/providing-answers-to-code-that-is-different-but-more-efficient-than-the-ops-co)*

As the concerned question is about finding a sporadic / irregular bug for which optimizations increase its probability, it seems not a "code asking" question. And it's possible that the bug doesn't directly result from the code quality (which at first sight seems somehow OK, but not perfect), and for me I couldn't state that at first sight without digging farther.

The "more efficient" gives useful insights, but isn't clear for me if it's appropriate to conduct a code review on few hundred lines of code here.

Comment: Side note: "code review" is generally used as term to review reasonably working code to make sure that code satisfying whatever criteria team has for the code/design. Finding problems in some non-working code usually called "debugging"...At very least the codereview.stackexchange.com  uses "code review" in that exact meaning - review of working code for "best practices"...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I agree that the main points of code reviews is enforcing best practices and design goals/criteria's. But generally we have **peer** code reviews for assessing security risks, reliability risks, resources risks, etc. Reviews for which the purpose is to prevent unreliable code to ever reach integration nor production stages,  best practices or not. C langage really requires second sight from peers. Debug in production is very costly, so **weakness** and bugs should be detected earlier as possible. And best practices can't alone prevents catastrophic failures.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov   It seems to me that this kind of **peer** code reviews are commons today. It was in our usages for at least ten years from my point of view. As example, **peer** code review is here mandatory to merge any pull request even on the dev branches.

Comment: Just because the code is lengthy doesn't necessarily mean a code review is needed. Minimal doesn't equal short. So it could just be a very difficult exception that only occurs because of the interplay of many factors. On the other hand it also could just be insufficient abilities of the question creator to minimize the example. Without looking at the content, nobody will know.

Comment: “[I] await [code review being done by colleagues] from other developers / askers” — This is definitely an unreasonable expectation. *It would be nice* if that were the case but I would estimate that the vast majority of software companies do *not* perform consistent code review. Of course all the best shops do, and the evidence in favour of this practice is overwhelming, but best practices and reality are divided by a vast chasm.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'll keep that in mind. I somehow thought that peer reviews were commons nowadays, seems it's mainly common in big IT circles. Best practices are somewhat still a work in progress too, not always uniformly understood.

Comment: Why isn't migration to [CodeReview.se] a standard option in the close reasons? I see this issue a lot.

Comment: @Chris Schaller As NateEldredge tells it below , CodeReview don't want to see code with known bugs :  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask
And the related code was in fact... messed up to the point the OP asked on SO for help on random crashs when compiled with -O2 (not so surprising once you've seen its use of the stack).

Comment: @Zilog80 fair enough, this question is less of a candidate than others, but in general I see code review as a more patient audience and you get back and expect detailed _and_ opinionated responses. I think posters need to be more aware that such sites exist. Adding it as a migration target would encourage more SO reviewers to go there and have a look once in a while.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I closed the question.

The code in question is 518 lines. I mainly code in Go, but I have written
several *whole programs* that are smaller than that. So in essence, OP could be
asking us to debug their whole program. Except in the minority of cases,
**that is not acceptable**. The code has almost certainly run afoul of:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Each case will be different of course, and in some situations the length will be
warranted. This is not one of those cases. Here are some indicators of a bad
question. Each one of these by itself does not guarantee bad question, but
several stacked doesn't look good:

- New user
- No edits to question
- Bunch of comments on question
- Little or no responses to comments from OP
- One or more highly upvoted comments on the question
- Low or negative question score
- More than one existing close votes

Comment: OP did explain that they tried to reduce the example, but all their attempts made the bug no longer reproducible.  If anything I think the problem is that there is too *little* code - it's just isolated functions and can't be compiled and tested.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have managed to build the provided code with a guess on the NETSocket struct and a minimal tree build, however, as i had a closer view of the code, i'm afraid the bug stated by the asker directly results from few(?) improper initializations and predicaments. It would require some time to ascert that. (and yes i'm a kind one)

Comment: @NateEldredge I've checked twice. Line 210 and 226, stack allocated  net_avl_node inserted in the tree. I should run it to be sure, but i clearly think asker needs far more a code review than our answers...

Comment: @Nate If providing less code stops the bug from happening, then it seems like an ideal time for the OP to debug their code carefully. Essentially: if removing code stops the error from occurring, then the fault is probably in the removed code (whether that provides incorrect input to other methods, or is failing all by itself).

Comment: @Llama - Not necessarily.  For some kinds of bugs, removal of code may have indirect effects; e.g. changing timing, changing memory cache behavior, removing "serendipitous" synchronization.  This may make the bug you are looking for disappear ... without actually fixing it.  The fact that this bug is sensitive to optimization level implies that there is some sort of "undefined" or "unspecified" behavior at the root of the user's problems.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I pretty much never have qualms about insisting on a MRE, for creating one is a powerful debugging approach in its own right, not merely a hoop to jump through to obtain our cooperation.  My sympathy for the "I tried but couldn't" OPs is limited -- I do feel for those who are truly in over their heads, but they need more and different help than we generally can provide.

Comment: Well, if any change hides the bug, then the example is by definition minimal even though it may still be very long.  Maybe we can't help but it's worth a try.  The problem for me was that the example wasn't *complete*.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no SME on C - even if I dink around a bit with it and C++ in what used to be called "spare time" - but if this were a language I was familiar with, and a circumstance that I was familiar with, I'd look for these telltale signs in the question.

- **Is it comprehensively answerable?**  Is there a single answer here or explanation (and yes, explanations *can* be long) that can be provided to satisfy the question for the OP?
- **Did the OP provide enough details in their question?**  As an SME, could I reasonably answer the question with everything that the OP supplied to me?  If I couldn't, what's missing?  Do I need to ask for it?
- **Does the question still involve some coding process?**  Is this something that a normal programmer would do if they wanted to program or deliver on something?  Is it something I would do?  Is it something that seems practical or reasonable to do?

If it satisfies the above, I don't see a reason to *avoid* answering it.

Comment: Is it comprehensively answerable?  My guess, probably.
Did the OP provide enough details in their question? Yes and no. Asker provide many context elements on the compilation and its researches on the matter. But the provided code is partial (just a tip on NETSocket struct) and asker did not fully describe the bugs effects (no dump, no SIG info). As the latter are more SME domain, it could be understandable and i guess there's low probability we could get them. I'll give a try and ask for a crash dump.

Comment: Does the question still involve some coding process?  Clearly somehow for me. C chat @Kamiccolo suggest me to drive the asker on CodeReview@StackExchange and let the question focus on a potential non code quality related bug. A good idea.
So for now, it seems that what concerns a code review should not be "answer" on this question.

Comment: @Zilog80: CodeReview.SE doesn't want to see code with known bugs, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @NateEldredge Noted. That means that we should address defects that affect code stability on this question and forget which remains about code review.

Comment: "no dump, no SIG info" - This goes back to Makoto's second point, "Did the OP provide enough details in their question?", if the dump and SIG info is required then the answer to that question would be "no".  It does not matter since the author of the question being asked about deleted it.

Comment: @SecurityHound To be fair, OP wasn't asked to provide them. We were going to ask for them, and the question was closed in between.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the time or desire to review 500 lines of code, don't. But I imagine that someone else out there will "do the job" of the OP or OP's colleagues, and answer the question. There are several reasons to do someone else's job:

1. Boredom
2. Exercise/Challenge
3. Curiosity

If enough people see the question, one of them may have the motivation to answer the question, even if you think it would take you too much valuable time to do that.

So, I suggest "handling" such a question by moving on and doing nothing (except the usual downvote/upvote).

I agree with you that this site is "not the right place for that". However, having this here is not too bad, and there are questions that are much more harmful than that. Such "find my bug" questions would be bad if they flooded the site. But the site is currently flooded by much worse stuff, so don't delete or close the relatively harmless questions.

---

In addition, I see two possible scenarios when an answer to such a question can benefit many other people, and not only OP. This is a great indication that such question may be good for the site.

1. Someone answers the question, describing the techniques he used, like test cases, breakpoints, adding print-statements, etc.
2. Someone "answers" the question by suggesting a general technique for finding your bug. In the case of this question, the answer is just "run `valgrind` and see where your bug is". Probably this is too short and generic for an answer, so a comment.

We don't know if some good answer will appear, so the question is only potentially good - the question is good only if it gets an answer. Weird.

Comment: Regarding theses two scenarii, should we then create a question "How to properly debug a C/C++/rust/etc. binary executable" and post an answer with tools, technics, etc. ? And post the link on "find my bug" questions ?
I've done a quick SO search and , to my surprise, it seems there is to this day no questions of this kind...

Comment: Digging farther, there is questions about debugging with VS, debugging with Android, debugging so library, debugging with emacs as IDE (i love doing that), but i found no general debugging questions.

Comment: Maybe [Debugging executable on Linux] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177035/how-to-debug-windows-executable-in-linux) could fit. However, even if debugging executables is environnement specific for tools , there is a general modus operandi applicable everywhere (crash dump, stack traces, etc.).

Comment: Yes, "How to debug?" might be a good question. But one would have to make its scope well-defined and narrow enough, so that the answer(s) would be short enough to read. I don't feel I can do that.

Comment: Between those that ask poor questions that usually boil down to not putting enough effort before looking for help, and those who for whatever reason indulege that - it's voluntary. But the problem is in how it affects this community as a whole. 

People should come here to learn so that they can solve their problem themselves now, and benefit from new knowledge in the future. Even if some people willingly do others job, I don't think SO should have a reputation of a place where you can offload your effort on volunteers for free.

Comment: There is a difference between "I am lazy" and "I don't know how to get started". You cannot know for sure which question that is. Many lazy questions are easy to identify, but this one is different.